# JTI claim value is not changing after access token refresh

Tags: jwt, openid-connect, access-token, refresh-token

While creating some custom flows in IdentityServer4, I have discovered, that JTI claim stays same for each refreshed access token.

If you look into the RFC 7519 (https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7519#section-4.1.7), value of JTI claim "MUST be assigned in a manner that ensures that there is a negligible probability that the same value will be accidentally assigned to a different data object". As for me any refreshed token is "different data object". So I was surprised why JTI is not changing?
Can anybody explain it? Is it feature or is it bug :)

Comment: I consider the data object here to include the payload, probably also the signature...?